# Does 给你 mean "Here you go?"

Tags: meaning

I found a very short sentence on [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/1670075). All it says is, "给你。"

That literally means "Give you," but what does it really mean? My best guess is that I could say it as I give something to you, kind of like, "Here you go."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your guess is correct. You use it when you hand over or give something. You can translate it as "there you are, here you are, here you go".

For example a teacher might say it while handing out some study material. A student of course should use 给您 when handing in his exam papers.

You can also add what you are giving. For example 给你一本书.

Comment: and you could even simply say "给" in this situation, which is casual or could be not impolite.

Comment: I think I've also heard "拿着" in that sense, would that make sense? I couldn't find many example sentences online.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means "here you go".  This certainly confused me when I arrived in China.  (To be fair, the English "here you go" doesn't make any literal sense either.)

Directly translated, [给你](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BB%99%E4%BD%A0) indeed means "give you".  However in English, when someone *gives* you something, we usually expect it to be a gift.  When using 给你, it doesn't necessarily mean a gift: it might do (e.g. in  给你个礼物) but not always.

When interacting with a shopkeeper, 给你 doesn't mean a gift.

#### [给](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BB%99) (gěi) vs. [送给](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%80%81%E7%BB%99) (sòng gěi)

> **给**你一百元

This is a normal thing to say when giving a 100 yuan note to a shopkeeper.  **It's not a gift: it counts towards the payment of something**, and the shopkeeper will still give you change.  It's a good way to highlight how you know it's 100 yuan you have given them [so they can't later claim you gave them a 50 yuan note].

> **送给**你一百元

This is the version of "give" which implies it's a gift.  Thanks for the 100 yuan.

Answer (score 0):

In a colloquial context, 给你, "give you", especially when spoken threateningly, could mean "take this", as in "I'll rearrange your face"